# Could not find generator - custom generator for my engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, rails-engines

I have written some custom generators for my engine to simplify my work.
I want to generate some files direct into my engine.
However the generator is accessible only from the dummy app and not direct from the engine.

```
my_engine_root:# rails g custom_generator  
Could not find generator custom_generator.

engine_dummy_path:# rails g custom_generator  
Everything works...
```

I tried to require the generators path, but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: generators are meant to be used from a rails app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, isolate your custom generator to a separated engine, so you can add this excerpt to "script/rails" or "bin/rails", depending on rails version, in the engine which you want the generators available:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

then add rails, your custom generator gem and all dependencies to the Gemfile of your engine

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'my_custom_generator', :path => "/path/to/my_custom_generator"
```